# Why does shift+clicking the icon of a minimized program cause it to open epic slowly?

Tags: macos, mac

If you minimize a program, then shift+click the icon to bring it up again, the sliding animation is slowed down immensely, making it open at an almost comical pace. I don't understand why this is a feature. Can anyone explain the reasoning behind this functionality?

Comment: @Buscar웃 shift-click on an icon of a minimized window in the Dock -> slow open

Comment: to early for me in the morning, I try to used the space+click :(

Answer (score 4):

Just like Cover Flow, it [seems](http://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/mac-os-x/how-minimize-mac-osx-window-dock-genie-slow-motion-effect) to be a “Steve Jobs wanted to use it in a Keynote”-Feature.